# Codeblocks crashes after inputting a character while some other code is also executed

Tags: c, struct, crash, scanf, codeblocks

I'm a newbie so spare me if it's a common question already answered.

[problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joFBI.png)

[works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWdHM.png)

So basically my code works fine if I don't enter any data in structure but if I do enter data in structure it crashes after taking some random character input which is not even the part of structure.
Code below-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
struct student
{
    char name[50];
    int roll;
    float marks;
};
main()
{
    int n,i;
    char a;
    printf("Enter the number of entries (students): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        struct student s[i];
        printf("\n\nEnter the name of student %d: ",i);
        scanf("%s",s[i].name);
        printf("Enter the roll number of %s: ",s[i].name);
        scanf("%d",&s[i].roll);
        printf("Enter the marks of %s: ",s[i].name);
        scanf("%f",&s[i].marks);
    }

    printf("Now enter any character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &a);
    printf("\n\n%c",a);      //CRASHES AFTER HERE

}
```

Comment: Your use of an array inside the loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, it's not the IDE that crashes, but your program. And you usually use a *debugger* to catch crashes as they happen.

Comment: Lastly a hint about the actual problem: For an array of `i` elements, what is the valid range of indexes? Remember that indexes are *zero* based.

Comment: thanks for the help, solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I was supposed to declare structure variable as

```
struct student s[n];
```

outside the loop and of course had to start the indexing (and loop) from zero (to less than n).